# Custom UIViews strange behaviour

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

I am implementing  one `Custom View` inside a `ViewController` of my app that I call twice with different parameters, but there is a strange behaviour in this.

As you can see in the picture both `views` are a group of `UILabel`s and 2 `UIImageView`s, both `Custom View`s are equals, actually the same code to create those two views.

[image]

I have used colours to know where is each `Label` and see the `background`. Grey and orange are the 2 `backgrounds`. first views is ok in its place, but second attributes are outside the real view(grey one). Anyone knows if there is any problem instantiating views like I do? Is there any better way?

I have used this code to instantiate this `views` in the `ViewController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view addSubview:self.sherpaViewDescubridor];

    [self.view addSubview:self.sherpaViewConquistador];
}
#pragma mark - Custom Getters 

-(WPSherpaView *)sherpaViewDescubridor
{
    if(!sherpaViewDescubridor){
        CGRect sherpaFrame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 320, 125);

        sherpaViewDescubridor = [[WPSherpaView alloc] initWithFrame:sherpaFrame];
        return sherpaViewDescubridor;
    }
    return sherpaViewDescubridor;
}


-(WPSherpaView *)sherpaViewConquistador
{
    if(!sherpaViewConquistador){
        CGRect sherpaFrame = self.sherpaViewDescubridor.frame;
        sherpaFrame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(sherpaFrame) + 5;
        sherpaViewConquistador = [[WPSherpaView alloc] initWithFrame:sherpaFrame];
        sherpaViewConquistador.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        return sherpaViewConquistador;
    }
    return sherpaViewConquistador;
}
```

Here it is the Custom View code:

```
@implementation WPSherpaView
@synthesize aliasLbl, nameLbl ,pointsLbl,positionLbl,profileImg,flagImg, viewNameLbl, warCryLbl;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        CGRect firstLabelFrame = {
            .origin.x = kMarginLeft,
            .origin.y =  self.frame.origin.y + 10.0 ,
            .size.width = self.frame.size.width - (2*kMarginLeft),
            .size.height = kNameViewHeight,
        };


        viewNameLbl = [[WPCustomLabel alloc] initWithFrame:firstLabelFrame];
        [viewNameLbl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:KMediumFontSize]];
        [viewNameLbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        viewNameLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        [self addSubview:viewNameLbl];


        CGRect centreViewFrame = firstLabelFrame;
        centreViewFrame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(firstLabelFrame) + 10.0;

        UIView *centerView  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:centreViewFrame];
        centerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

        [self addSubview:centerView];


        // LEFT IMAGES

        CGRect imageProfileFrame = {
            .origin.x = 0,
            .origin.y =  0 ,
            .size.width = kImageSize,
            .size.height = kImageSize,
        };


        profileImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageProfileFrame];
        profileImg.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [centerView addSubview:profileImg];

        imageProfileFrame.origin.x = CGRectGetMaxX(imageProfileFrame)+ kMarginLeft;
        flagImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageProfileFrame];
        flagImg.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        [centerView addSubview:flagImg];


        // RIGHT LABELS

        CGRect labelFrame = imageProfileFrame;
        labelFrame.origin.x = CGRectGetMaxX(imageProfileFrame) + (2 * kMarginLeft);
        labelFrame.size = kSizelabel;


        aliasLbl = [[WPCustomLabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
        [aliasLbl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:KMediumFontSize]];
        [aliasLbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        aliasLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        [centerView addSubview:aliasLbl];


        labelFrame.origin.y += kSizelabel.height;
        labelFrame.size.height = 15.0;
        nameLbl = [[WPCustomLabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
        [nameLbl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:KMinFontSize]];
        [nameLbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        nameLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        [centerView addSubview:nameLbl];


        labelFrame.origin.y += kSizelabel.height;
        positionLbl = [[WPCustomLabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
        [positionLbl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]];
        [positionLbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
        positionLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        [centerView addSubview:positionLbl];


        labelFrame.origin.y += kSizelabel.height;
        warCryLbl = [[WPCustomLabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
        [warCryLbl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]];
        [warCryLbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        warCryLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        [centerView addSubview:warCryLbl];


        centreViewFrame.size.height = CGRectGetMaxY(labelFrame) + 5 ;
        centerView.frame = centreViewFrame;

        // BORDER VIEW

        CGRect bordeFrame = self.frame;
        bordeFrame.size.height = 0.5;
        bordeFrame.origin.y = self.frame.size.height - 0.5;
        bordeFrame.origin.x = kMarginLeft;

        UIView *bottomBorder = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bordeFrame];
        bottomBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        [self addSubview:bottomBorder];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Is this the full code? Since the problem is related to the small (colored) views, not the big ones. The code you posted only created the big ones, and they're positioned correctly.

Comment: No, I also Have the big one. but if the first one is correct. why is not the second one? It is the same code, do you want to watch it?

Comment: Yes, please post it, since no one could find any problem in the current code. Most likely you mixed up `frame` and `bounds` somewhere in the code with the small ones, just as some people mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
CGRect firstLabelFrame = {
    .origin.x = kMarginLeft,
    .origin.y =  self.bounds.origin.y + 10.0 , // <----
    .size.width = self.bounds.size.width - (2*kMarginLeft), // <-----
    .size.height = kNameViewHeight,
};
```

Comment: Thank you. it has worked. I dont know very well the difference between bounds and frame. Caleb has explained it well. but I dont get it very well

Comment: Make sure you read the docs, since bounds / frames difference is very very important. Basically `frame` is the view's position *relative to its parent*; `bounds` always has origin (0, 0) unless the view is scrollable, and *has nothing to do with its parent*.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're probably mixing up `frame` and `bounds` when you position your view in the superview. `frame` is the bounding rectangle expressed in the superview's coordinates, `bounds` is the same rectangle expressed in the view's own coordinates. If the superview happens to be located at *its* superview's origin, as your orange view probably is, then there's no difference. The gray view, on the other hand, has it's origin displaced by the orange view's height. When you use that `frame` to locate your `sherpaView`, the `sherpaView` is displaced by that same amount.

Use `bounds` if you want the coordinates *inside the view* and `frame` if you want the coordinates *of the view*.

I'm having a little trouble following your code, but I think that if you change this:

```
CGRect sherpaFrame = self.sherpaViewDescubridor.frame;
```

to this:

```
CGRect sherpaFrame = self.sherpaViewDescubridor.bounds;
```

you'll probably get the result you want.

Comment: I think that it is creating like two sherpaViweConquistador. one with backGroundColor gray and without elements. and the other with elements but without color.

Comment: even doing this  `CGRect sherpaFrame =CGRectMake(10, 125, 320, 125);` It still do the same.